# Signed java applet blocked by security setting

Tags: java, security, applet, jar-signing

I have a very basic Java Applet signed with my own certificate. When I try it out on my website I get the message that the application is blocked by security settings.

This is what I did.
I signed the jar file using the jarsigner tool:

```
jarsigner -keystore keystore.p12 -storetype pkcs12  -tsa http://timestamp.comodoca.com/rfc3161 TestApplet1.jar codesign
```

When I verify the jar it all looks fine to me:

```
$ jarsigner -verify -verbose -certs TestApplet1.jar

s k      415 Thu Oct 09 12:19:18 CEST 2014 META-INF/MANIFEST.MF

      [entry was signed on 9-10-14 12:19]
      X.509, EMAILADDRESS=test@test.nl, CN=codesigning 2014, OU=Test, O="Test BV ", L=Stad, ST=ZH, C=NL (codesign)
      [certificate is valid from 11-8-14 11:19 to 11-8-15 11:29]
      X.509, CN=CA-TEST (ca-test)
      [certificate is valid from 23-2-11 9:37 to 23-2-16 9:46]

         496 Thu Oct 09 12:19:18 CEST 2014 META-INF/CODESIGN.SF
        4666 Thu Oct 09 12:19:18 CEST 2014 META-INF/CODESIGN.RSA
smk      226 Tue Oct 07 16:31:54 CEST 2014 .classpath

      [entry was signed on 9-10-14 12:19]
      X.509, EMAILADDRESS=test@test.nl, CN=codesigning 2014, OU=Test, O="Test BV ", L=Stad, ST=ZH, C=NL (codesign)
      [certificate is valid from 11-8-14 11:19 to 11-8-15 11:29]
      X.509, CN=CA-TEST (ca-test)
      [certificate is valid from 23-2-11 9:37 to 23-2-16 9:46]

smk      370 Tue Oct 07 16:31:54 CEST 2014 .project

      [entry was signed on 9-10-14 12:19]
      X.509, EMAILADDRESS=test@test.nl, CN=codesigning 2014, OU=Test, O="Test BV ", L=Stad, ST=ZH, C=NL (codesign)
      [certificate is valid from 11-8-14 11:19 to 11-8-15 11:29]
      X.509, CN=CA-TEST (ca-test)
      [certificate is valid from 23-2-11 9:37 to 23-2-16 9:46]

smk      792 Tue Oct 07 16:34:30 CEST 2014 nl/test/applet/TestApplet1.class

      [entry was signed on 9-10-14 12:19]
      X.509, EMAILADDRESS=test@test.nl, CN=codesigning 2014, OU=Test, O="Test BV ", L=Stad, ST=ZH, C=NL (codesign)
      [certificate is valid from 11-8-14 11:19 to 11-8-15 11:29]
      X.509, CN=CA-TEST (ca-test)
      [certificate is valid from 23-2-11 9:37 to 23-2-16 9:46]

           0 Tue Oct 07 16:33:50 CEST 2014 nl/
           0 Tue Oct 07 16:33:50 CEST 2014 nl/test/
           0 Tue Oct 07 16:33:50 CEST 2014 nl/test/applet/

  s = signature was verified 
  m = entry is listed in manifest
  k = at least one certificate was found in keystore
  i = at least one certificate was found in identity scope

jar verified.
```

I created a very basic html file with the  tag:

```
<body>
    <p>Test page TestApplet1</p>

    <applet code="nl.test.applet.TestApplet1.class"
        archive="TestApplet1.jar"
        id="TestApplet1"
        height="0" width="0">
    </applet>

    <script type="text/javascript">
        alert(document.getElementById("TestApplet1").helloWorld());
    </script>
</body>
```

But when I deploy it on my test website and try to run the applet the applet is blocked by security settings. The message I get is: "**Your security settings have blocked an untrusted application from running**".

When I set the security level to "*Medium*", using the Java Control Panel, and then I open the webpage again I get the security warning: "**An unsigned application from the location below is requested permission to run.**"

What is wrong with my approach?

By the way, I already imported my CA certificate to the trusted root CA's in both the IE certificate store and the certificates managed in the Java Control Panel.

Any suggestion is welcome.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need do following steps:

- sign all jars by your key
- make sure you using https.
- if you using http or self signed ssl cert for https you need add you host into security exceptions list(jcontrol -> Security tab -> Edit Site list)

Comment: Your say: "make sure you using https";  That implies that you cannot run an applet from a non SSL site?! I never read that in any documentation about applets. But, sure I will give it a try. BTW my final applet will run on a https site so if this is the solution, then I will be happy ;)

Comment: It very important to have valid cert to sign applet and valid web site cert. Otherwise your customers will have lot of annoying warnings.

Comment: I tested my applet on a SSL site and indeed no complains. I still use my own certificate chain, the SSL site has a certificate issued by the same CA as my code signing certificate. When we go public we will use a certificate issued by VeriSign, or another trusted third party.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at the [this link](http://www.jade-cheng.com/uh/ta/signed-applet-tutorial/)

Basically, self signed applets behave in the way you noticed. This is because of the security standards of Java. If you want to remove the warnings, you need to buy a certificate.

Hope this helps.